# Ver las tablas de una base de datos sqlite atravez de codigo c#

Tags: c#, sqlite

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto y ocupo sabes que tablas existen en determinada base de datos y despuésdeslpegarle al usuario las tablas. Algo como en la imagen, pero con codigo c#

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma simple podria ser ralizando una consulta a las tablas de definicion de la db

[SQLite Schema Class for VB.Net and C#](https://www.blakepell.com/2013-12-13-sqlite-schema-class-for-vbnet-and-csharp)

si analizamos el codigo veras que para obtener los nombre de las tablas realiza una consulta a la tabla `sqlite_master`

```
select name from sqlite_master where type='table' order by name
```

ejecutando esa consulta con ado.net obtendras los nombres de las tablas